# Angular Material - Best Practice for Customizing the Framework

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I just started a new job and have been preparing to build out a new application using Angular 2. The company has many applications and opted to use Angular Material for development speed as opposed to custom component development. However we have a designer who is bringing a new look and feel to the application and it doesn't look anything like the Material Design theming standards. We still want to use Angular Material as the components are easy to implement. My questions are:

1. Is it a common practice for developers to use Material for functionality while completely overriding the theme and implementing a custom look and feel?
2. If so, any advice on what to look out for in regard to gotchas?
3. If not, any advice on a better way to go about using components of other frameworks that are not tying you down to any specific look and feel?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: The question is pointless without specifying what 'new look and feel' is. But most likely no, Material design is opinionated, and ng2-material customization comes to stylesheet overrides. Maybe PrimeNg can offer more.

Comment: The new look and feel is not defined yet as it is going through design considerations, but some initial mockups I saw basically look nothing like material design. For example the design for the forms are completely different than Materials forms; they have standard input fields that are distinguishable rectangles as opposed to the single line seen in Material. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: By the way, I want to thank you for directing me to PrimeNg. This looks perfect for what Im doing.